# Is changing plymouth-theme different in 16.04?

Tags: plymouth

I have some plymouth themes on the path /usr/share/plymouth/themes.

But I cannot set them. I first tried `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` then chose the theme. after that `sudo update-initramfs -u`

There were no errors. But it's not working.  Plymouth-manager is not working too (installed but not running).
I use Ubuntu 16.04 amd64